Применение стилей к группам точек внутри точечной диаграммы google docs
Есть точечная диаграмма в Google Docs. В ней есть 2 столбика - значения по Х и по У. В итоге у нас получается группа точек, распределённая на диаграмме.
Задача.
Сделать так, чтобы в той же таблице, которая используется для построения точек (по Х и У), можно было указать атрибут для каждой точки (добавить 3й столбик и в нём указать, напротив координат точки). И чтобы согласно этому атрибуту (или стилю, я не знаю как правильнее), точка получала разные характеристики на диаграмме (другой цвет и форма).
Пока что я знаю как менять каждую точку вручную, через: Изменить диаграмму - Редактор диаграмм - Дополнительные - Серии - Добавить форматирование (и тут можно конкретную точку менять вручную). Но точек сотни и хотелось как-то сразу выставить для каждой атрибут, какого она должна быть цвета. То есть как-то присвоить ей группу, чтобы она учитывалась диаграммой.
Подскажите пожалуйста, как это реализовать.
Спасибо.
